# Why does css prefer a general rule over a class rule?

Tags: html, css

let's say I have following html-code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>


    <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And following css-fragment:

```
div {
    color: red;
}

.a {
    color:blue;
}
```

Why now is "Test" colored red and not blue? The tag-element is in the d-level, while the class element is in the c-level, thus the class-rule is higher and thus it should be applied, but it don't - why? Why doesn't the children of `<div class="b">` inherit properties from `<div class="a">` - or to put it more accurate: Why do I have to explicitly set color = inherit?

_

Comment: Because you have a div nested in class a.  If you changed the css to .b instead of .a it would be blue.

Comment: Latest rule for your p tag is rule for div. Open your code in inspector and check rules order.  div -> .a -> div

Comment: I think of it like a hierarchy. So if you color the container, you can't see what color the object is inside of the container...does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

There is no class "b" in css-fragment. Then,

(div class="b") is similar to (div) with no class.

Answer (score 0):

Because .a only affects on its own div and "div" its for all divs.

So if you do this:

```
    <div class="a">
        <div class="b" id="b">
            <p>Test</p>
    
    #b { color: blue; }
or
    .b { color: blue; }
```

Your test will be blue.